# Option for msbuild to output what it will build, without building?

Tags: msbuild

Curious if there's a way to ask msbuild to do a dummy pass where it will quickly tell you which binaries it will build, without actually building them?

Comment: Ask Microsoft at https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild